# How to sum in Excel with month logic?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

Mentione in the picture, I have 2 Excel sheets, **Sheet 1** with ID **Q1** and **Z1**, and NAME in column and month in rows. And in **Sheet 2**, I have ID **Q1** and **Z1** with the amount in month column.

My requirement  in **Sheet 1** **C3** - if I place formula it should calculate **Sheet2** Jan month **Q1** total amount and same like all. I have tried `SUMIF()` formula 
In C3 =sumif(select column P:Q : R ,select P3 :Q3 :R3, "greater or ="&A3,C2:D2:E2,lessthan or ="&EOMONTH(P3,0)) and its not work.

Apologize for lessthan and greathan symbol i cant find in ma mob to show in formula and apologize too for grammer mistake.

[image]

Comment: Can you write your whole SUMIF formula? That should be correct. It'll help us troubleshoot why its not working.

Comment: Your question "as-is" is very unclear. Please [edit] your question with more information so we can assist you.

Comment: Can you add the result you would expect for this example?

Answer (score 0):

*Check the Screen Shot.*

[image]

Formula in Cell C3 of Sheet 1: `=SUMIF(O2:O6,"Q1",P2:P6)`

**NB:** No need to workout with EOMONTH or others since your Jan Data are in Column P only.

Comment: Nice to hear from you @safwan keep asking.